# how do I define an address with a module and an offset in c++

Tags: disassembly, c++, memory

I'm trying to define an address so that I can edit its memory later, however I can't figure out a way to access it.

The base address is `"program.exe"+00D23440` and has an offset of +30

Normally you would just take the address and add its offset, but there's a string involved here.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Modules have a base address where space is allocated for it.
For example in 32 bit this can be 0x00400000. 
So "program.exe" is just a placeholder for BASE_ADDRESS+OFFSET 
You need to know or find out the base address of your program. 
you can do this manually or dynamically 
for an example of a dynamic solution see here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564148/how-to-get-the-starting-base-address-of-a-process-in-c
In some situations, the base address can change.
This is why a dynamic solution is be preferred.

Comment: His 'base address' is 00D23440 though, and I'd expect the DLL-load base address to be 4K aligned at the very least. So I suspect he means something else.

Comment: Possibly, it would be useful if OP would post more information on what he is trying to achieve or methods that he's tried. I can see that he needs to find the address that the executable is loaded at (instead of "program.exe"), and he has another offset besides 0x00D23440, which is '+30'. Are they talking about a pointer?
e.g. [BASE_ADDRESS+RVA]+offset